# How do I access the current guild name and ID that my bot is running in?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I know you can do `<Client>.guilds` to find out all the guilds your bot is in, but I don't know how to find just the current guild (the name and ID of it)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by current guild? Do you mean the server that you receive the message from?

Comment: Yes, the current server a message was sent in

Comment: message.guild.name, message.guild.id ?

Comment: You should learn how to read the DJS docs, as it's essentially the most useful tool you can use when developing bots. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Comment: Will do, thank you so much!

Comment: To be honest the discordjs documentation is not that complete. It's often hard to find specific info. Telling people to just read the doc is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [message.guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) to get the full guild object. If you want the name or id you can use this object to get them.

```js
message.guild.id // 12345678901234567
message.guild.name // Some Discord Server
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks!